# How can I invoke different versions of the same assembly in a single .NET Core application?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a very simple assembly that is used to take a piece of data and calculate a value. This assembly has no references to other assemblies and only exports a single class:

```
namespace MyAssembly
{
    public static class MyClass 
    {
        public int GetValue(byte[] input) 
        { 
            ... 
        }
    }
}
```

This assembly is shared between a client and server. The client sends its data and the result it got to the server, and the server needs to validate that the result is correct.

#### The Problem

There are 20 different versions of the client, each with a different version of the assembly that performs slightly different calculations.

My server has all of the assemblies available and needs to invoke the correct version that matches the client's. I can guarantee that there are no target framework or runtime compatibility issues with any of the assemblies.

#### Alternate Solutions (that I don't want)

I can achieve this by spawning child processes that include the correct assembly, but this operation occurs tens of thousands of times per second and the invocation is somewhat time-sensitive, so this isn't viable.

In a similar approach, I can write a host process that my application communicates with using IPC, but this adds an incredible amount of complexity and potential points of failure.

It seems like creating a new AppDomain for each assembly would have been the ideal solution, but .NET Core doesn't maintain support for this.

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: I think approach with IPC will be best here. This is only alternative to appdomain in .net core. It is just designed in a simple way. There is process, there is another process, they can communicate. Done. No appdomain or whatever excess concept. You can pretty easly decorate them, in a simple Request/Response interface.

Comment: You might want to have a look at AssemblyLoadContext. For an example look here https://github.com/dotnet/samples/blob/master/core/tutorials/Unloading/Host/Program.cs

Answer (score 0):

> I can achieve this by spawning child processes that include the
>   correct assembly, but this operation occurs tens of thousands of times
>   per second and the invocation is somewhat time-sensitive, so this
>   isn't viable.

This is probably the best approach.  But instead of a *new* child process every time, make the child process stay running and respond to your parent process via IPC requests.  The child process would become a server for the particular assembly version being interrogated for the calculation.   In the parent process, you keep track of handles to various child process for specific assembly versions and call the appropriate one.  If one doesn't exist for the assembly needed, create one, keep it open, and save it for later.  It'll only be slow the first call per assembly (if that's a problem, then this solution isn't viable); but then fast after that.  If resource constraints demand it, you may need to implement a TTL on your cache of child processes so that if an assembly version hasn't been needed in a long time it can get unloaded to make room for fresher child processes.